# Exposing ipv6 ports in docker containers

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6, nat, ports

I have an application which needs to listen on ipv6 for a specific port. I have exposed it in the docker file, and I'm running the docker engine with `DOCKER_OPTS="--ipv6"`, but I can't get docker to properly map the ports over ipv6.

Port shows up when using `docker inspect {name}` (see below for output - redacted to get rid of superfluous stuff). For some reason I can't get it to route the IPv6 stuff, however (and it looks like the ports are only being exposed as ipv4 from the output below).

How do I go about getting the port (9084) to be accessible via ipv6 connections to the host, in the same way that the other two ports are accessible over ipv4 connections to the host?

```
[
    {
        // [...]
        "HostConfig": {
            // [...]
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8883/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                    }
                ],
                "9084/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9084"
                    }
                ],
                "9094/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9094"
                    }
                ]
            },
            // [...]
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            // [...]
        },
        // [...]
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "40c7aa89b266",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8883/tcp": {},
                "9084/tcp": {},
                "9094/tcp": {}
            },
            // [...]
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "97923c78571e880f267b56f4d86a7338e2f7a878d20b9961ae208af9c2bc6b64",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8883/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                    }
                ],
                "9084/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9084"
                    }
                ],
                "9094/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9094"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/97923c78571e",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "cdddc3cd29e3cb40f68cf696f0d6dffadd08aa5bf256cd12cef180f04795ee83",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "fe80::242:ac11:4",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "fe80::1",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "3371009b227abe4e8992fbd9a56ea662ee76fd692b6d7080045d5deb055e29e3",
                    "EndpointID": "cdddc3cd29e3cb40f68cf696f0d6dffadd08aa5bf256cd12cef180f04795ee83",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "fe80::1",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "fe80::242:ac11:4",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: you're not opening any ports on ipv6, just ipv4. try adding `::` as the host ip, which is roughly the ipv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @MarcB: I'm having some trouble doing that. I tried using `::9084:9084`, `[::]:9084:9084` and `:::9084:9084` in the ports configuration but I just get errors. There's very little documentation on this is seems.

Comment: It *seems* that docker can't parse IPv6 addresses in compose (which I'm using to set up the containers) https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2663